# JPA GeneratedType Sequence with initialvalue

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am maintaining a live java application which is developed using Spring JPA with MySQL 5.7.

It's entities uses GeneratedType.AUTO for @Id and I want to use GeneratedType.SEQUENCE since table doesn't have a regular increment primary keys.

Currently tables have live data, I referred that using initialValue property I can give a starting number to my primary key. So I can skip the existing primary keys and start from newer.

But My question is if I hard corded the initialValue in my entity, will it be a problem when I deploy the application several times, or do I have to change the initialValue everytime when I need to deploy a new version of the application?